# Phonegap/Cordova WebSql transaction not firing

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, web-sql

I'm using cordova's latest version (3.5) and I want to save some data using WebSQL but when I call database.transaction(query,success,error) it does nothing. Both my sucess method and error method have alert() to notify error or success but none of them fire.

Here's my code:

```
    function onDeviceReady(){
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", 1, "PhoneGap Demo");
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
    }
```

As I said the alert boxes are not being displayed. What could be the problem? 
For more
information: **I'm using Cordova 3.5 and being tested on an iPhone simulator. 
I executed the code on chrome with my laptop and seems to work.**

Comment: You need to add callbacks as parameters in .executeSql, i.e. tx.executeSql(sql, values, successCB, errorCB);

Comment: I've added the callbacks but still not working. It's so strange! Why in my laptop's browser is working? @zvona

Comment: @MarcOrtiz first and foremost check whether `onDeviceReady()` is getting fired by putting an `alert()` call inside. If `alert()` does not fire that means the phonegap app is not configured properly. Check If you have included `cordova.js` in the index.html file. Hope you have added `document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady,false);` in you index.html file.

Comment: @frank Yes I've already checked the onDeviceReady function gets called and works. I've also added alerts() after the code: db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB); and before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment : cordova 3.4
device : Emulator ( Nexus 7)
OS : Android KitKat 4.4
I just checked your code and got the error "Insufficient Number of arguments" on line

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", 1, "PhoneGap Demo");
```

As per the API doc there should be four arguments, I changed the code to

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 1000);
```

and it worked. The last argument is the initial size of the database in bytes.

Hope the above solution works for iPhone as well.

I used **console.log()** call as well as alert() for debugging.